# Get json from post request android not working

Tags: android, json, httprequest

Hello I want to get json from http post request. I used this site: http://www.hurl.it/ to test my request and it's working well [image: http://i.imgur.com/qn5gK4D.png] so I wanted to do same request in my code.

Something in my code doesn't work:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static String postHttpResponse() {
        Log.d("post", "Going to make a post request");
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Log.d("post", "Im inside :-)))))");
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
            URI uri = new URI("https://mywebsite.com/Home/GetHomeTemplates");
            post.setURI(uri);
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Skip","100"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Take","50"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type","-1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PluginType","-1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Proportion","-1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sort","6"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SortDirection","1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Categories","[]"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Controls","[]"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsFree","true"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsSystem","true"));

            post.setHeader("Host","mywebsite.com");
            post.setHeader("Accept","application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8, charset=utf-8");
            post.setHeader("Referer","https://mywebsite.com/Templates");

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Log.d("post", "HTTP POST succeeded");
                HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = messageEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("post", "HTTP POST status code is not 200");
            }           
        Log.d("post", "Done with HTTP posting");
        Log.d("post", "Post" + response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", "Post " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response.toString();
```

My logcat with post filter:

```
09-25 19:49:05.290: D/post(26343): Going to make a post request
09-25 19:49:05.290: D/post(26343): post Im inside :-)))))
09-25 19:49:05.290: D/Exception:(26343): Post null
```

So it's supossed to be that code inside try/catch isn't running.

**Edit:**

There wasn't log "Im inside :-))))" because i was filtering for string "post" in logcat search. I also debugged and checked that my parameters aren't passed to my request.

I've edited my params as @Almer Nakano suggested but it still doesn't see parameters.

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Skip","100"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Take","50"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type","-1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PluginType","-1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Proportion","-1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sort","6"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SortDirection","1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Categories","[]"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Controls","[]"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsFree","true"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsSystem","true"));
```

Comment: Did you remember to include the internet permission in the Manifest?

Comment: why dont you debug your application

Comment: @erad yes i'm using webview to load content from web and it's working

Comment: Can you check the log? Another issue that could be happening is that you are sending a bad POST request and you're getting a timeout issue that isn't triggering yet because the timeout hasn't been reached.
Does it work if you just take out the try/catch and run it normally?

Comment: The problem for them, is that it does not even enter the try/catch. "Im inside" is never printed. I see no logical reason for that, either.

Comment: This is going against all rules of logic :O What happens if you comment out the whole try-catch-block except Log.d("post", "Im inside :-)))))");?

Comment: You tell the server that the content type is json. But you are not sending json but name value pairs.

Comment: `"Done with HTTP posting"` put that in the try block. Also put `Log.d("post", "Post" + response.toString());` in the try block. You are misleading yourself.

Comment: `Log.d("post", "" + e.getMessage());`. Bad info. Better: `Log.d("Exception: ", "" + e.getMessage());`.

Comment: @greenapps and @0101100101 that issue about `Log.d` was my fault. I was filtering in logcat for text _post_ when my log has not such name.

Comment: My remarks were not about filtering. My remarks were about log statements in your code on the wrong place. One will not say 'done with http posting' when there is an exception.

Comment: @greenapps ok i updated question. When i have code like you proposed my app catching exception with message "null". It's propably fault with parameters. Thank you :-)

Comment: Post the stacktrace please. Don´t filter. Put e.printStacktrace(); in catch blocks first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure whether the log manager guarantees that log messages are printed; there are buffers and complicated things involved, maybe it filters out some messages when necessary ?

The following sentence from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) is bugging me: "That means that if your log message is filtered out, you might be doing significant work and incurring significant overhead."

Try to use something other than Log.d to check if your code is run, or maybe increase the log level ?

Comment: Ok i found that there is something wrong with `˛params.add(new BasicNameValuePair();` I'll try repair that

Answer (score 0):

Try switch your Raw List params for this

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

You can also create a json String with your params and pass it like :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonString));
```